# How do you add modules to be loaded in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, modprobe

I would like to add some modules to be be loaded in Ubuntu 22.04 (The same works in ubuntu 20.04)

```
root@localhost:~# echo nvme_rdma >> /etc/modules
-bash: /etc/modules: Read-only file system
```

Is there a reason that this file is on a read only file system and how does one load modules on boot for Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Generally one would use `udev` to handle module loading at boot time 

Comment: only if there was a physical device that necessitates the module for a driver is my understanding. In the case where there is no physical device, and needs to be loaded on boot, the procedure is to use the modules file. Maybe I'm wrong? In this case, we are attempting to connect to an NVME over fabric server.

Comment: Using NVMe Drives and Creating an NVMe over Fabrics Network https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/data-flash-part-ii-using-nvme-drives-and-creating-nvme-over-fabrics-network

Comment: `sudo chmod 0644 /etc/modules`

Comment: Yes. just change the file permissions. Silly, I guess sometimes you just need some extra eyes after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change file permissions.

```
chmod 0644 /etc/modules
```